# Identifying an assortment of lists whose elements make up the exact elements in a larger list

Tags: python, list, comparison, combinations

Python 3.

**Preamble**

So I have a list of elements, which may be ordered like this (or any other way):

```
List = [c, d, a, c, b]
```

Lets order it to make things easier:

```
List = [a, b, c, c, d]
```

So the list may have duplicates and has a length between 1 and 10.

The user will choose a range number, for example:

```
r = 3
```

The range number is part of a logic that produces the number of lists that contains all the possible combinations of 'List' subsequences for lengths 1 to r. Each combination may be permuted in any way. Considering 'List' and 'r' in this example the user would get the following selection of lists:

```
%Lists of length 1.  
ListSelection1 = [[a], [b], [c], [c], [d]]

%Lists of length 2.
ListSelection2 = [[a, b], [a, c], [a, c], [a, d], [b, c], [b, c], [b, d], [c, c], [c, d], [c, d]]

%Lists of length 3.
ListSelection3 = [[a, b, c], [a, b, c], [a, b, d], [a, c, c], [a, c, d], [a, c, d], [b, c, c], [b, c, d], [b, c, d], [c, c, d]]
```

These lists will be arranged in another list, like this:

```
ListSelections = [ListSelection1, ListSelection2, ListSelection3]
```

**The problem**

How can I identify all possible combinations of (sub)lists in 'ListSelections' which together contains the same selection of elements as 'List'? Order of the elements does not matter. Regarding the example made above, accepted combinations of lists would be [b, c] and [a, c, d], or [b] + [c] + [d] + [a, c]. You get the point.

I need to identify all correct list-combinations and the positions of these lists in 'ListSelections'.

Comment: Do you want to keep duplicates or not ?

Comment: You mean different permutations/orderings of lists that make up the elements in 'List'? Like this: [b, c] and [a, c, d] <-> [a, c, d] and [b, c]. I only need all successful combinations of lists. I do not need every successful permutation. I would only want one of the two examples above to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want to find is the set of the partitions of a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). To do so you can use `sympy` as follows:

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_partitions
res=[p for p in multiset_partitions(["a","b","c","c","d"])]
```

Output:

```
[[['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']],
 [['a', 'b', 'c', 'c'], ['d']],
 [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['c']],
 [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd']],
 [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c'], ['d']],
 [['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c', 'c']],
 [['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c'], ['c']],
 [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'd']],
 [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'c'], ['d']],
 [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['c']],
 [['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['c'], ['d']],
 [['a', 'c', 'c', 'd'], ['b']],
 [['a', 'c', 'c'], ['b', 'd']],
 [['a', 'c', 'c'], ['b'], ['d']],
 [['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c']],
 [['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b'], ['c']],
 [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'd']],
 [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['d']],
 [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['c']],
 [['a', 'c'], ['b'], ['c', 'd']],
 [['a', 'c'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']],
 [['a', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'c']],
 [['a', 'd'], ['b', 'c'], ['c']],
 [['a', 'd'], ['b'], ['c', 'c']],
 [['a', 'd'], ['b'], ['c'], ['c']],
 [['a'], ['b', 'c', 'c', 'd']],
 [['a'], ['b', 'c', 'c'], ['d']],
 [['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['c']],
 [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'd']],
 [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['c'], ['d']],
 [['a'], ['b', 'd'], ['c', 'c']],
 [['a'], ['b', 'd'], ['c'], ['c']],
 [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'c', 'd']],
 [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'c'], ['d']],
 [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['c']],
 [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['c'], ['d']]]
```

Comment: Dav2357, you hit it on the head! This function is exactly what I need. 

I was a bit confused at first. The partition pattern looked a lot like what the Bell number would be used to calculate the number for, but 36 is not a Bell number. I realized that this is a consequence of (omitted) duplicate patterns which have been generated because of the 2 c's in 'List'. 

All I need to do now is make sure permutations of the combinations are recognized as the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Your specification is a bit confused, but I suspect you either want 'permutations' or 'combinations':

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Python has a library that does this for you.

`output = [itertools.permutations(input, r_) for r_ in range(r)]`